# Conditions ensuring that conditional law of a process belongs to a given exponential family

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations, stochastic-filtering

Let $(X_t,Y_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be a pair of $\mathbb{R}^n$-(resp. $\mathbb{R}^m$)-valued stochastic processes on a filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\geq 0},\mathbb{P})$, defined through the SDEs:
$$
\begin{aligned}
dX_t & = \mu(t,X_t,Y_t)\,dt + \sigma(t,X_t,Y_t)\,dW_t^1\\
dY_t & = m(t,X_t,Y_t)\,dt + s(t,X_t,Y_t)\,dW_t^2,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\mu,\sigma,m,s$ are all suitable uniformly-Lipschitz functions and $(W^i_t)_{t\geq 0}$ are independent Brownian motions of compatible dimensions with the above dynamics.

In [Chapter 11 of Lipster and Shiryaev's book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-13043-8), conditions on $\mu,\sigma,m,s$ and the initial laws of $X_0$ and $Y_0$ are given ensuring that the conditional probabilities:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(X_t \in \cdot\mid \sigma(\{Y_s\}_{0\leq s<t}\right),
$$
are all $\mathbb{P}$-a.s. Gaussian measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Fix an exponential family of probability measures $\mathcal{F}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$.  *Are there known conditions in the literature ensuring that:*
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(X_t \in \cdot\mid \sigma(\{Y_s\}_{0\leq s<t}\right) \in \mathcal{M} \qquad \forall t \geq 0 \,\mathbb{P}\text{-a.s?}
$$